# Openlayers - Turf.js Get distance between two Points using EPSG:3857

Tags: openlayers, turfjs, proj4js

I want to show the user the distance from the last drawn point to the cursor. In order to do so I need to add a change listener to the geometry of the feature.

Every time the user moves the mouse this change will get triggered and I need to calculate the distance. So in order to do so I want to use Turf.js. But the problem is that output distance is way to big. I think it has to do with the coordinate system I use.

In my project I the coordinates are in `EPSG:3857` and I think the distance function expects `ESPG:4326`. I have tried to use ol proj in order to convert. But then I get an error stating: Uncaught TypeError: destinationProjection is null

`olProj.transform(geom.getCoordinates()[0].slice(-3)[0], 'EPSG:3857', 'ESPG:4326');`

```
      listener.value = sketch.value.getGeometry().on('change', (evt) => {
        const geom = evt.target;

        var from = turf.point(geom.getCoordinates()[0].slice(-3)[0]);
        var to = turf.point(geom.getCoordinates()[0].slice(-2)[0]);
        console.log(turf.distance(from, to));
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is null because `'ESPG:4326'` should be `'EPSG:4326'`.  But you do not need turf to do that

```
new ol.geom.LineString(geom.getCoordinates()[0].slice(-3, -1)).getLength()
```

will give length of the segment in projection units, or

```
ol.sphere.getLength(new ol.geom.LineString(geom.getCoordinates()[0].slice(-3, -1)))
```

will give haversine length of the segment